# What's the combination of vectors with all coeffiencts between 0 to 1？

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes

Assume a combination of the form:
$\vec{S}=\sum_ip_i\vec{v}_i$ with $0\le p_i\le 1$, what is this combination called?

And considering the set:
$$\mathcal{S}=\{\sum_ip_i\vec{v}_i \mid 0\le p_i\le 1\}$$
What are its properties? For example, it's obviously convex, and for finite $\{\vec{v}_i\}$, it is a  convex polytope. But how many vertices does it have? assuming there are $n$ different vectors $\{\vec{v}_i\}$

Comment: I'm not sure how much help this is, but it's the convex hull of the collection of $2^n$ vectors: $\{p_i \vec{v}_i \mid p_i=0 \text{ or } p_i=1\}$, so it looks like an $n$-dimensional hypercube, or a projection of such a hypercube onto a space of lower dimension if the vectors are not linearly independent. (Look at the case of $3$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which generically look like a hexagonal shadow of a cube.)

Comment: Sorry the summation sign were missing before

Comment: See convex hull https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull ...or convex linear combination https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination

Comment: @SammyBlack: You haven't stated this correctly. There are really just $n+1$ vectors in that list, but you mean to look at various sums.

Comment: Do we have $\sum_i p_i=1$?

Comment: no such normalization constrain, so it is not a convex linear combination

Comment: You're right, @TedShifrin, I meant the collection of vectors $\sum p_i \vec{v}_i$ over all tuples $(p_1, \dots, p_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$.

Comment: "*what is this combination called*" a linear combination, I guess.